# How to create an element query in PHP with custom field names in variables?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, elementcriteriamodel, php, elementquery

I'm trying to dynamically create an element query in PHP where the custom field criteria come from an array of strings. Something like this...?

```
$users = User::find();
$users->group($groupList);

foreach ($criteria as $key => $value) {
    // Each key value is the handle for a custom field and the
    // field value used as criteria
    $users->$key($value);
}

$users->all();
```

How can I use a custom field name in a string as a parameter?

**Edit** If I don't chain the criteria, I also get a deprecation error when I iterate over `$users`...Is there a better way to do that, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Craft::configure()` for that.. imagine your array looks like

```
$criteria = [
    'age' => ['and', '>=30', '<=50'],
    'enabled' => false
    'status' => null,
]
```

You can do

```
$query = User::find();
Craft::configure($query, $criteria);

$users = $query->all();
```

Or you can just use the parameter based syntax instead of the functional one

```
$users->$key = $value;
```

You'll receive a deprecated error when you don't fetch your users. Your so called `$users` variable hast actually nothing to do with `users` it's a really bad name because one might think `users` store information about a list of users but that's not the case. `$users` is a `Query` that looks for `elements` with the type `craft\elements\user` in your database. You'll receive your list of `users` when you execute your `Query` with `one()`, `all()` or something like that.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and report back. Thanks, Robin!